# C# dynamic data parse to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net-core

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);
DateTime mydt=DateTime.Parse( data.operationStartDate);
```

But i get below error at Parse line.

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 4):

The explanation of the accepted answer:

`data.operationStartDate` has a type of `JValue` (a Newtonsoft.Json type). That can't be passed into `DateTime.Parse()`, but it has an explicit cast operator to cast to a string.

It also has an explicit cast to `DateTime`, so in your case, you can just call

```
   DateTime mydt = (DateTime) data.operationStartDate;
```